# Error when want to change data in csv file in java

Tags: java, list, csv, if-statement

Here is my customer.csv file:

```
1, Ali,1203456789, Normal
2, Siti,134567890, Normal
3, Bob,1568980765, Normal
```

I want to change the Normal status of the name I enter to Cased but my code seems got something wrong.And here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the customer you want to flag as Cased:");
    String flagCus = input.nextLine();
    ArrayList<String> customersFlagged = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("customer.csv"));
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        String[] items = lines.get(i).split(",");
        if (items[1] == flagCus){
            String enterList = items[0] + "," + items[1] + "," + items[2] + "," + "Cased";
            customersFlagged.add(enterList);
        } else{
            String enterList = items[0] + "," + items[1] + "," + items[2] + "," + items[3];
            customersFlagged.add(enterList);
        }
    }
```

I think the problem is the line if (items[1] == flagCus) ones but I am not sure where got wrong , I have been try to add a " " before my flagCus when doing the if statement but it still goes wrong. Can somebody help me check this code? Thank you for your attention.

Edit:I should have change the code (items[1] == flagCus) to (items[1].equals(" " + flagCus).Thank you guys for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: It's kind of funny, but nobody here has suggested to use any CSV parser. Technically, they suggest you to check string equality using the `equals` method, but it is making easy earnments for a question that falls into one of the most classic Java questions ever. My friendly suggestion: please use appropriate tools to solve your problems. (neither `ArrayList<String>` full of the records, nor `Files.readAllLines` that may be a performance killer, nor index-looped iteration (for an ArrayList though) over `.iterator()` or `for`, nor even `.split(",")` that breaks on `,`-containing values).

Answer (score 2):

When comparing two objects as opposed to primitive types, use `.equals()` not `==`. So:

```
items[1].equals(flagCus);
```

Answer (score 2):

To check equal String, use `"string".equals("other")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The Strings in the file have a space at the beginning (you are splitting on the commas).

```
1, Ali,1203456789, Normal
```

Either remove those from the input data or call:

```
if (items[1].trim().equals(flagCus)){
```

(as others have indicated in their answers, use `.equals` to compare `String` objects.

**complete code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the customer you want to flag as Cased:");
        String flagCus = input.nextLine();
        ArrayList<String> customersFlagged = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("customer.csv"));
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            String[] items = lines.get(i).split(",");
            if (items[1].trim().equals(flagCus)){
                String enterList = items[0] + "," + items[1] + "," + items[2] + "," + "Cased";
                customersFlagged.add(enterList);
            } else{
                String enterList = items[0] + "," + items[1] + "," + items[2] + "," + items[3];
                customersFlagged.add(enterList);
            }
        }
```